# Django could not perform queries on Postgres when request sent from fastapi

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, fastapi

I use Django as ORM and fastapi as endpoint layer. Here is my Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    command: bash -c "uvicorn contlika.asgi:celestial --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

the connections between `web` (Django Backend) and `db` (Postgres) is ok. So when I do queries within `web` container after the below command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

the object is created successfully and record is set in db tables.
But when I send request from fastapi - through swagger interface - I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have included the user and pass correctly in `setting.py`. Again the objects are being created successfully through Django command line utility.
It's worth nothing to say, everything was working fine when I had been working with sqlite db. I've faced with this issue when I change my db from sqlite to Postgres.
Where I went wrong? I can include the asgi.py if it's needed.

I tried including env variables in docker-compose and allowed all origins in `setting.py` and `asgi.py` as below:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and

```
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins = [str(origin) for origin in settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS] or ["*"], allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"],)
```

Comment: How are you giving a host to connect to in your FastAPI application? Your postgres library wouldn't know that it should connect to `db` over the network unless you give a hostname to connect to.

Comment: Well. Probably that's the issue. I've search a lot to find out how should I give a host to connect to in my FastAPI app. But all samples I've found were about working fastapi and postgres together without django. Could you please give me a helpful source with it? @MatsLindh

Comment: That depends on the first part of my comment: How are you connecting to your postgres database now? You're also running django - are you using django as an API that you're connecting to, or what is django's role in all of this? (if you're only using django for migrations and this is a new project, I'd consider using sqlalchemy with alembic instead of pulling in the whole of django to get migration support).

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes. I use Django as an ORM to read and write on db. i.e. I use Django querysets inside fastapi endpoint functions. I get parameters through functions decorated with fastapi router and communicate with db using Django Models and managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; The problem was the missing of `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable. I updated the env file by this line:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres
```

and updated the `api` section of docker-compose as below:

```
  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    command: bash -c "uvicorn contlika.asgi:celestial --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001"
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Thanks to @MatsLindh for giving the clue.

Comment: can you proceed to use this in a production environment? it's not safe to have the database url in plain text.